# How to push data from DB into FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following function that sets up some dynamic forms in one of my pages.

```
prepareClaseDispositivo() {
    this.dispositivos.forEach(dispo => {
        if (!this.labelDispositivos.includes(dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre)) {
            this.labelDispositivos.push(dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre);
        }
    });
    this.labelDispositivos.forEach(clase => {
        this.addDispositivos();
        const dispositivosByClase = [];
        this.dispositivos.forEach(dispo => {
            if (clase === dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre) {
                if (this.data.dispositivos) {
                    for (const d of this.data.dispositivos) {
                        if (d.descripcion === dispo.descripcion) {
                            console.log('match found');
                            // Add elements to FormArray
                            this.dispositivosForm.push(dispo);
                            console.log('added ', dispo, ' to formarray');
                        }
                    }
                }
                dispositivosByClase.push(dispo);
            }
        });
        this.dispositivosByClases.push({ nombre: clase, dispositivos: dispositivosByClase });
        if (this.data.edit) {
            this.dispoArrayForm();
        }

    });
}
```

Now, 'this.dispositivos' contains data retrieved from the database and 'dispositivoForm' is meant to be in charge of any options found there as selected in the form.

My question is, how can I add the contents of 'dispo' into the 'dispositivoForm' FormArray?

HTML in case it's needed:

```
<div formArrayName="dispositivosForm">
<div *ngFor="let clase of dispositivosByClases; index as i;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <h6>{{ clase.nombre }}</h6>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label></mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="dispositivos" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let dispo of clase.dispositivos" [value]="dispo.id">
              {{ dispo.descripcion }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FormArray requires an array of FormControls or FormGroups. Try to implement a method which generates you an form group of your *dispo* object and add this to your form array.

```
generateFormGroup(dispo: any) {
  return new FormGroup({
    dispositivos: new FormControl(dispo.dispositivos)
  });
}
```

```
dispositivosForm: FormArray = new FormArray([]);  // <-- instance your FormArray in the beginning of your component

prepareClaseDispositivo() {
    this.dispositivos.forEach(dispo => {
        if (!this.labelDispositivos.includes(dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre)) {
            this.labelDispositivos.push(dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre);
        }
    });
    this.labelDispositivos.forEach(clase => {
        this.addDispositivos();
        const dispositivosByClase = [];
        this.dispositivos.forEach(dispo => {
            if (clase === dispo.clase_dispositivo.nombre) {
                if (this.data.dispositivos) {
                    for (const d of this.data.dispositivos) {
                        if (d.descripcion === dispo.descripcion) {
                            console.log('match found');
                            // Add elements to FormArray
                            this.dispositivosForm.push(this.generateFormGroup(dispo));  // <-- add the generated form group here
                            console.log('added ', dispo, ' to formarray');
                        }
                    }
                }
                dispositivosByClase.push(dispo);
            }
        });
        this.dispositivosByClases.push({ nombre: clase, dispositivos: dispositivosByClase });
        if (this.data.edit) {
            this.dispoArrayForm();
        }

    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div formArrayName="dispositivosForm" *ngFor="let clase of dispositivosForm.value; index as i;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <h6>{{ clase.nombre }}</h6>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label></mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="dispositivos" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let dispo of clase.dispositivos" [value]="dispo.id">
              {{ dispo.descripcion }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can't get this to work. Basically I create the `generateFormGroup()` method and then call it on `prepareClaseDispositivo()` when the match is found to add the contents of `dispo` to the FormArray, right?

Comment: You also have to modify your html. Look at my edits

Comment: That change to HTML breaks the form (`Error: "Cannot find control with name: 'dispositivosForm'"` , `ERROR Error: "Cannot find control with path: 'dispositivosForm -> 0'"`), and goes against what I need to do (this case is about an edit form, but in the case I need to add a new entry it'll fetch nothing, for example.)

Comment: If you need more help pls provide a stackblitz project with a test scenario

Comment: App is pretty complex and relies on postgresql and laravel to function properly. Rerwitting the module to fit on stackblitz will take quite a lot of time.